# How to edit a Json key from an URL ( Android Studio )

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

So here's the deal , I already generated this Json URL :

https://api.myjson.com/bins/w7wuz

And I did some code om my app in order to read it. So far so good.

But I'm struggling a bit , trying to edit a key on my Json URL , to see if my app would update the value as well .

I hope I was clear with what I pretend. Thanks guys .

Comment: can you please explain more about why you are change your url.

Comment: I dont want to change my URL , I want it to be a static URL that will give me data throw time. But the information on the URL is allways the same , but I want to get diferent data from the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new parameter to your URL then possible otherwise not possible in my view.

Like :

```
https://api.myjson.com/bins/w7wuz?id=1
https://api.myjson.com/bins/w7wuz?id=2&name=kaushal
```